# Error Code: 1007. Can't create database 'CustomerDataService'; database exists 0.00029 sec

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to using MYSQL and MYSQL workbench. I have the error code above and not sure how to resolve that. Here is my code below

```
CREATE DATABASE CustomerDataService;

USE CustomerDataService;

CREATE TABLE Customers(
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName VARCHAR(1000),
    LastName VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId)
);

CREATE TABLE Emails(
    EmailId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
EmailAddress VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    IsSubscribed BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EmailId)
);

ALTER TABLE Customers ADD COLUMN EmailId INT;
ALTER TABLE Customers ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CustomerEmail FOREIGN KEY (EmailId) REFERENCES Emails(EmailID);
INSERT INTO Emails (EmailAddress, IsSubscribed) VALUES("abc@gmail.com", TRUE);
INSERT INTO Customers (FirstName, LastName, EmailId) VALUES("Fname", "Lname", 1);
SELECT * FROM Customers;
SELECT * FROM Emails;
```

Comment: To resolve it you have to stop trying to create a database which already exists.

Comment: If you want to run this script more than once then you have to clean up after it fails somewhere, or simply DROP the database before rerunning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the `CREATE DATABASE` line, or replace it with

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `CustomerDataService`;
```

Chances are that the scriptlet had already been run, and the tables already exist, too, so you may then run into `Table already exists` errors next.

The other, brute force, alternative would be to:

```
DROP DATABASE `CustomerDataService`;
```

But only try that if you are really sure you want to delete what is already there, and have a good backup just in case ...